# How to change line lengths in LineLegend

Tags: plotting

How can I shorten the lengths of the LineLegend[] lines in the following plot?

Is there a way to control line spacing as well?

```
styles = {Orange, Blue};
legend = LineLegend[styles, {"f", "g"}];
plot = Plot[{-Sin[x], Cos[2 x]}, {x, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, PlotStyle -> styles,
  Epilog -> Inset[legend, Scaled[{1, 1}], Scaled[{1, 1}]], ImageSize -> 72*3.375/2]
```

[image: Plot using LineLegend]

I am generating a figure for a publication where I want to control image size, font size, line widths, etc. in absolute terms, e.g., printers points.

Comment: Is LegendMarkerSize what you're looking for?  Please check the examples for this option on the LineLegend documentation page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First question answered, here we go with LegendMarkerSize:

```
legend = LineLegend[styles, {"f", "g"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 5];
```

Second question answered:
Customize a Grid for the legend using the Spacing option and use it in LegendLayout. Play around with Spacing values for horizontal and vertical adjustments. Here we go

```
table[pairs_] := Grid[pairs, Spacings -> {.5, 0}];
legend = LineLegend[styles, {"f", "g"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 5, 
   LegendLayout -> table];
```

..good luck with your publication :)
...some royalties on your publication, please, hi,hi,hi